# How to SpyOn native JavaScript functions? Such as .find()?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to mock `this.editedComponentDetailsData.find` in the following :

```
editButtonClicked(event) {
    let rowData = this.editedComponentDetailsData.find((row) => {
      return row.operationalSequenceNumber == this.rowKey;
    })
  }
```

This doesn't work:

```
 it('should do something', () => {
    let result=spyOn(subject.editedComponentDetailsData.prototype,'find').and.returnValue({prop1:''});
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign to the `editedComponentDetailsData` an property which is iterable like an empty array and then you can spy on find, but you just access this without the prototype just like inside your component.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
    TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      platformBrowserDynamicTesting())

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      providers: [
        AppComponent
      ],

      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    subject = fixture.componentInstance;
    subject.editedComponentDetailsData=[]; //mock with empty array
  });
  it('should do something', () => {
    let result=spyOn(subject.editedComponentDetailsData,'find').and.returnValue({prop1:''}); //the spy
  });
```

Comment: That was easy. Thanks.